# How to merge different MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, database, import

I have an old database which I want to import in the new one but they are different in columns. How do I import it without any loss or change to the old database ?

Comment: You should show both schemas (the old and the new one) as well. Also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, figure out which tables (and their columns) in the old DB match which tables (and their columns) in the new DB.

Then, create a sequence of INSERTs into the new DB with SELECTs from the old DB...

Check out [this part of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) documentation dealing with INSERT...SELECTs.